# Increase size of checkbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I really tried a lot to increase a size of checkbox in asp.net. using css style sheet but it doesn't work.

Might be I have done something wrong. I am try to increase the width, size and height of checkbox, but it doesnt happen yet.

Can anyone provide C# code or css code that can do this?

Comment: Hi,  this is totally possible in CSS.  you can go see my answer and maybe accept it as the good answer if it works for you ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do it.  A Checkbox is a windowed browser component.  The best you can do is to make your own control that LOOKS like a checkbox, but is actually made up of an image for each state.

Here are some examples of controls that use images instead of checkboxes:

- [ASP.Net AJAX AJAXControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx)
- [CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/checkboxdemo.aspx)
- [Checkboxes and radiobuttons](http://tomasp.net/articles/graphicalcontrols.aspx)
- [ImageCheckbox](http://www.i386.com/Products/i386UI/Examples/ImageCheckBox.aspx)

Comment: check out this link. and you got it..... http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/

Comment: It works in IE 6 and IE 7, but not 8, and not FF, and not chrome (and even in IE, its very pixelated).

Comment: @Sikender: Are you willing to use the AJAXControlToolkit (I recommend it)? If so, they have a toggle button control.  You can simply specify the images, and it works:  http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx

Comment: @Yannick Richard's solution works great as a css only solution.

Comment: You can do it. Minus 1

Answer (score 29):

In asp.net a checkbox will become a span with an input of type "checkbox"

In order to resize it,  just apply a css class to the asp.net checkbox and add this to your style sheet. the style must be applied to the the embeded input of the checkbox like this :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxName" runat="server" CssClass="ChkBoxClass"/>

.ChkBoxClass input {width:25px; height:25px;}
```

Comment: PLUS ONE for an awesome answer! Well done! Works like a charm for me!!!

Answer (score 3):

Having a html checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="fatty">
<label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>

fatty { /* Change width and height */
   width:4em;
   height:4em;
}
```

I got this from [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/).

Comment: no. i donot want to use html control. i am talking about .net checkbox control.

Comment: @Sikender: The asp.net checkbox control renders similar to Jason's example.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but I'll leave this here for anyone else that needs help making check boxes bigger.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(3); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(3); /* Opera */
}
```

Example provided in the code snippet.

```css
.scale1 {
    margin: 15px;
    -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(1); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(1); /* Opera */
}

.scale2 {
    margin: 15px;
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
}

.scale3 {
    margin: 15px;
    -ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(3); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(3); /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="scale1">
<label for="cb1">scale1 </label>

<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" class="scale2">
<label for="cb2">scale2 </label>

<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" class="scale3">
<label for="cb3">scale3 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, this doesn't worked for me:

```
   <asp:CheckBox id="requestAccountCB" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" runat="server"/>
```

but this worked:

```
    <style>
        #requestAccountCB { width: 20px; height: 20px }
    </style>
```

...

```
    <body>
       <form runat="server">
           <asp:CheckBox id="requestAccountCB" runat="server"/>
       </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this *can't* be done.

What you can do is **add a tag inside the checkbox and set a background image to that tag**. It's all done with css and it works perfectly.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label
{
background-image: url('images/off.gif');
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background-image: url('images/on.gif');
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>
```

The code can be found in  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/) fiddle.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772273/pure-css-checkbox-image-replacement).

**BTW**: if you're using ASP.NET like me, you can add the *label* tag as so:

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEmailForUnpluggedService" Text="<label for='thing'>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works perfect for me:

Html Rendered looks like this:

```
<span class="15465503">
    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_BB_SB_ScB_ucSR_rptR_ctl01_chkShortlist" 
     type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$BB$SB$ScB$ucSR$rptR$ctl01$chkShortlist");">
</span>
```

CSS to change the check box size is:

```
input[id$="chkShortlist"] {
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, if anybody still needs help with this - the multitude of answers above did not help me resize an ASP checkbox in an old WebForms application. Instead, adding the checkbox as a standard HTML Input element (as type="checkbox"), as opposed to an ASP:CheckBox, and then setting runat="server", helped me to be able to control this with inline styles, whilst still being able to control this in the code behind. E.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbInputDamagedStatus" style="width:1.5em; height:1.5em; display: inline-block;" runat="server" />
```

and

```
cbInputDamagedStatus.Checked = true;
```