# Pure CSS checkbox image replacement

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors

I've got a checkbox list in a table.  (one of a number of CB's on the row)

```
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="custom_image" value="1" id="CB1" /><label for='CB1'>&nbsp;</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="custom_image" value="2" id="CB2" /><label for='CB2'>&nbsp;</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="custom_image" value="3" id="CB3" /><label for='CB3'>&nbsp;</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="custom_image" value="4" id="CB4" /><label for='CB4'>&nbsp;</label></td></tr>
```

I'd like to replace the checkbox image with a pair of custom on/off images and I was wondering if anyone had some better understanding of how to do this with CSS?

I've found this "CSS ninja" tutorial, but I'll have to admit to finding it a bit complex for me.  http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

As far as I can tell, you're allowed to use a pseudo class

```
 td:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox] + label
 {
     background: url('/images/off.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
     height: 16px;
     padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 }
```

My expectation was that by adding the above CSS the checkbox would at least default to displaying the image in the OFF state and then I'd add the following to get the ON

```
 td:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
     background: url('/images/on.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
 }
```

Unfortunately, it seems I'm missing a critical step somewhere.  I've tried to use the custom CSS3 selector syntax to match my current setup - but must be missing something (The images are size 16x16 if that matters)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked

EDIT:
I'd been missing something in the tutorial where he applies the image change to the label and not the input itself.  I'm still not getting the expected swapped image for checkbox result on page, but think I'm closer.

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin called [Uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) which does a very nice job of this.

Comment: sadly we're using prototype and I can't change that (the knock on effects would be crippling).  I'd look for a prototype plugin (fancy forms) ... but part of my "personal" goal is to get it to work using the non-js method.  I know it can be done (see tutorial) I *feel* like I'm close... and I think that knowing how to do it would improve my ability to work with future, similar tasks.  Obviously, if it's square-peg-round-hole impossible I'll give up and move to a JS trick of some kind.

Comment: Wait — "Pure CSS" as in CSS without images or CSS without Javascript?

Comment: oh - i meant "semi pure"  i'm definitely using images at the moment, but I suppose it'd be possible to use a "data / mime " tag to put the image inside the CSS.  (i saw an article on that recently, though the exact location eludes me at the moment)

Comment: You could probably use a css gradient with a border, with a span inside the label also styled with CSS. IMHO, who cares, the image works fine. #crazycss

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I haven't heard of Uniform before - it's great. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, "Pure CSS" as in CSS with javascript and/or extra dom nodes?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You are close already. Just make sure to hide the checkbox and associate it with a label you style via `input[checkbox] + label`

**Complete Code: http://gist.github.com/592332**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/

Comment: This relies on `label` element, that can be missing. see my answer below.

Comment: I think if you set opacity to 0 instead, you can still achieve the tab stop behaviour.  Not 100% on that tho.

Comment: without name and for
http://jsfiddle.net/ajshres/4huzr/2486/
when using for large table could be handy when using against ajax

Comment: @Valipour Objection rejected. If your checkbox has no label, put a label on your checkbox. That fixes your UI and WAG problems in the same swoop.

Answer (score 46):

Using javascript seems to be unnecessary if you choose CSS3.

By using `:before` selector, you can do this in two lines of CSS. (no script involved).

Another advantage of this approach is that it does not rely on `<label>` tag and works even it is missing.

Note: in browsers without CSS3 support, checkboxes will look normal. (backward compatible).

```
input[type=checkbox]:before { content:""; display:inline-block; width:12px; height:12px; background:red; }
input[type=checkbox]:checked:before { background:green; }​
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/1/

and this one with images:

http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/6/

Comment: This looks very promising but, alas, it doesn't seem to be working on Firefox 14.0.1 Mac

Comment: Tried this with images and it still shows the original checkboxes behind the image, so not very good for small or odd-shaped images.

Comment: OK I just found out that this can be fixed by setting the checkbox to `visibility: hidden` and the `:before` to `visibility: visible`. I assume that this breaks the backward compatibility though.

Comment: The jsfiddles, they do nothing. Shows up as normal checkboxes. Firefox 27.

Comment: Same with Windows (sorry, have to use it at work): Works in Chrome 35 but not Firefox 30.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why this does not work in modern browsers: It does not work because <input> cannot have :before and :after pseudo-elements.

Comment: working fine for me in Brave (Chrome) 2023, finally, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

**Use Images Like Checkboxes and Radios Pure Css**

[image]

```css
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't used this idea exactly as it is, but I've used large chunks of it, which has given me a huge jump start on achieving what I need to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: It is good that you answered with a real world example. But it is always good to post or at least point out the actual/core technic instead of leaving that to the poor guy (me!).. out of all the above 200 lines, I'm pretty sure the actual logic will be in handful of lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for further more customization,

Check out the following library: https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Thanks