# Checkboxes in web pages – how to make them bigger?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

The standard checkboxes rendered in most browsers are quite small and don’t increase in size even when a larger font is used.  What is the best, browser-independent way to display larger checkboxes?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

In case this can help anyone, here's simple CSS as a jumping off point. Turns it into a basic rounded square big enough for thumbs with a toggled background color.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #555;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    background: #abd;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: @GabrielW That's right. Just use the equivalent for the others

Comment: @taylorcressy Except for IE (also IE 11) http://caniuse.com/#search=Appearance - but worked fine for other browsers. Thanks!

Comment: would be nice if there was a tick inside too :)

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for sharing. I was wondering how you deal with the checkmark showing up. With the background just set to a color, the white checkmark in the box is no longer visible. Is there an easy solution? I've tried add a html entity for the check in a :before, but wondering if there is an alternative

Comment: I used a darker color for the checked background color and it's not so bad without a "check"

Answer (score 66):

Actually there is a way to make them bigger, checkboxes just like anything else (even an iframe like a facebook button).

Wrap them in a "zoomed" element:

```css
.double {
  zoom: 2;
  transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="double">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hello" value="1">
</div>
```

It might look a little bit "rescaled" but it works.

Of course you can make that div float:left and put your label besides it, float:left too.

Comment: Note that on Firefox (as of version 36), this will result in a very blurry appearance. It scales well in Chrome, though. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tzp858j3/

Comment: is there no better solution which does NOT look scaled?

Comment: Can't `zoom: 2` and `transform: scale(2)` be directly applied to the checkbox? Why does it need a wrapper?

Comment: Thanks! looks like your code takes more browsers into account then I could ever test with, but it works on everything I've tried. Especially nice on my I-phone, where checkboxes just about become dots! BTW, you can put smaller fractional scaling (like 1.5) in the places where this snipet puts "2", and for a medium size checkbox.

Comment: zoom: 2 and transform: scale(2)  was all I needed applied to the div wrapping the checkbox

Answer (score 32):

Try this CSS

```css
input[type=checkbox] {width:100px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Not totally cross-browser (it's better to set a class in HTML and use the class selector in CSS), but this might be a better solution than mine. +1

Comment: Note that this makes fuzzy looking controls in some browsers as the native control that is scaled up is a fixed sized image.

Comment: I was using width and height for example purposes. Probably a combination of Harmen and my solution is the way to go as you may need more styling than CSS can reasonably provide.

Comment: This will only work in some browsers, and not in many modern ones.

Comment: This works on ipad safari where checkboxes often need to be larger to make it easier for users to click.

Comment: works in IE11, chrome 36 and iPad Safari 7 (iOS 7.1)

Comment: Major limitation is that it doesn't work at all in Firefox (as of Firefox 36) and will in fact look quite unnatural (the checkbox is regular sized but padding around it fills the 100 x 100px area.

Comment: I gave you a downvote - this answer does not work in Chrome.

Comment: As of right now, 2021, it seems that this answer is working and is the simplest. Chrome, Edge tested.

Answer (score 23):

I tried changing the `padding` and `margin` and well as the `width` and `height`, and then finally found that if you just increase the scale it'll work:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: I tried a number of these solutions and this was the only one that didn't cause other issues, also worth noting that scale is very widely supported by browsers so very cross browser compatible. I created a class so I could apply it to only the checkboxes I wanted to, which could be used to scale anything: .scale-up-20 {transform: scale(1.2);}

Answer (score 7):

Pure modern 2020 **CSS only** decision, without blurry scaling or non-handy transforming. And with tick! =)

Works nice in Firefox and Chromium-based browsers.

So, you can rule your checkboxes purely **ADAPTIVE**, just by setting parent block's `font-size` and it will grow with text!

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.0em;
  height: 1.0em;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border: 0.125em solid #555;
  position: relative;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  background: #adf;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90%;
  left: 0.0625em;
  top: -0.25em;
}
```

```html
<label for="check1"><input type="checkbox" id="check1" checked="checked" /> checkbox one</label>
<label for="check2"><input type="checkbox" id="check2" /> another checkbox</label>
<label for="check3" style="font-size:150%"><input type="checkbox" id="check3" checked="checked" /> bigger checkbox </label>
```

Comment: Working in internet explorer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that works in most recent browsers (IE9+) as a CSS only solution that can be improved with javascript to support IE8 and below.

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" name="checkboxName" value="whatever" />
  <label for="checkboxID"> </label>
</div>
```

Style the `label` with what you want the checkbox to look like

```
#checkboxID
{
  position: absolute fixed;
  margin-right: 2000px;
  right: 100%;
}
#checkboxID + label
{
  /* unchecked state */
}
#checkboxID:checked + label
{
  /* checked state */
}
```

For javascript, you'll be able to add classes to the label to show the state. Also, it would be wise to use the following function:

```
$('label[for]').live('click', function(e){
  $('#' + $(this).attr('for') ).click();
  return false;
});
```

EDIT to modify `#checkboxID` styles

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772914/190135 for a link to full source code for this technique

Answer (score 1):

I'm writtinga phonegap app, and checkboxes vary in size, look, etc.
So I made my own simple checkbox:

First the HTML code:

```
<span role="checkbox"/>
```

Then the CSS:

```
[role=checkbox]{
    background-image: url(../img/checkbox_nc.png);
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checked[role=checkbox]{
    background-image: url(../img/checkbox_c.png);
}
```

To toggle checkbox state, I used JQuery:

```
CLICKEVENT='touchend';
function createCheckboxes()
{
    $('[role=checkbox]').bind(CLICKEVENT,function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    });
}
```

But It can easily be done without it...

Hope it can help!