# Larger checkboxes on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked through many Q&A here on Stackoverflow and other sources about how to make a larger checkbox. All solutions provided do not show a simple checkbox bigger.

There are many solutions. Many are from several years ago. All are different.

I am interested in creating checkboxes that are 2x or 3x larger on mobile device. In fact if they are larger on desktop browsers that is just fine also.

What is the best way to get a larger checkbox in 2016?

I don't want "weird" checkboxes where there is an funny looking check mark, or some "alternative checkmark".

Just a normal checkbox... but larger. Also... The text describing the checkbox should align properly.

Thanks

Comment: Does setting the width and height of your checkboxes via CSS not work?

Comment: @Hydro That won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkboxes in web pages – how to make them bigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137255/checkboxes-in-web-pages-how-to-make-them-bigger)

Comment: Take a look at this CSS3 CodePen example - https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

Comment: Specifically, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22303413).

Comment: I used @Josh link and came up with this https://codepen.io/slindsey3000/pen/dXZwBj - The last one is nice and big. Now will it line up with text and labels?

Comment: Also... the person who suggested that my question is answered. No... I don't want a change in background color. I say clearly that I want a normal checkbox... just larger

Answer (score 1):

You can scale any html element with the transform scale... Checkbox is an HTML element, it can be scaled as well and you can specify different scales relative to different viewports in order to make the scaling compatible with the device it views on..

```
input[type=checkbox] 
{
 -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
 -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
 -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: I currently use this approach but it throws alignment off. For example if my checkbox is the first element in a row, when you "scale up" it gets bigger in all directions. It even expands off the screen in situations where the checkbox is the all the way left. How can I use this and still make everything line up?

Comment: http://cappedin.com/parlay_bets/parlay_entry#event-746902 - I use scale for the checkboxes all the way down the page. They blow up outside of background.

Comment: This might fix that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481090/html-css-how-to-resize-checkboxes-without-overlapping

Answer (score 1):

I would go with simple setting `width`/`height` plus `-moz-appearance` for firefox, and flexbox for aligning.

```
<div class="form-holder">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox">This is label for checkbox</label>
</div>

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }  
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }  
}

.form-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13zmdd7q/2/)

Comment: The demo fiddle has a tiny checkbox. Do you know how to make a larger checkbox? Nevermind. Just saw on mobile. Looks great.

Comment: This is nice. How come it only enlarges on mobile? How can I make it enlarge on desktop also? @Bogdan-Kustan

Comment: well it uses media queries, You can resize fiddle result tab to see difference