# Image replacement for Checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a custom image for checkboxes, as discussed in this question:

[Pure CSS Checkbox Image replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772273/pure-css-checkbox-image-replacement)

My checkboxes appear in a grid, so don't need a label associated with them.  However, I find that if the label isn't present, the technique discussed in that question doesn't work.

For example, here's the relevant css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]  {
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background: url('/resources/img/checkBox-unchecked.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background: url('/resources/img/checkBox-checked.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Declaring just a simple `input` doesn't render the image:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

However, if I modify the css, appending the `+ label`, and append a label to the markup, as discussed in the solution, it works:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background: url('/resources/img/checkBox-unchecked.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label  {
    background: url('/resources/img/checkBox-checked.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

<input type="checkbox"><label></label>
```

This renders as expected.

Why does the first solution not work?

How can I acheive this without having to add labels that aren't required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left the following in your first example:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

That will make it *"not render."*

Now, having removed that trifling little style, you'll likely ask

> Okay, the control shows up now... so, why doesn't the background image show up?

That's because you don't have any real control over how radio-buttons, check-boxes, combo-boxes, file-upload controls, etc are styled. The label solution works because you can happily style a label to the full extent of css. The controls I've mentioned? Not so much...

Comment: Thanks!  What the other question/answer didn't make clear (that you have) is that the solution doesn't style the checkbox, it styles the label.  The checkbox is hidden.  It's all just smoke'n'mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but, if you set all input checkbox to 0 opacity, won't if effectively hide the whole checkbox? Maybe try the method mentioned in this post : http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: That solution uses javascript and still injects extra dom nodes... which is what the OP is trying to avoid.