# Is the :before pseudo-element allowed on an input[type=checkbox]?

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850353/1127114) describes how to style checkboxes using CSS3 without requiring a `<label>`:

```
input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content:""; display:inline-block; width:12px; height:12px; background:red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/1/)

This works in Chrome 22 but not in Firefox 15 or IE 9.

Given the lack of support in the latter two browsers, **is Chrome's behavior valid according to the CSS3 specification?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is uncharted land; the specifications do not clear things up. The [CSS 2.1 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> “Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.” And, debatably, INPUT could be seen as a [replaced element in CSS 2.1 sense](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element).

One might think that these pseudo-elements cannot be used for elements that cannot have any content (i.e., with EMPTY declared content), such as IMG or INPUT. However, the wording mentions IMG, and [Appendix D](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) has a rule with the selector `br:before`.

And CSS3 Selectors, one of the few parts of CSS3 that have reached recommendation status, does *not* clear things up. [It says](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content):

> “The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements can be used to describe generated content before or after an element's content. They are explained in CSS 2.1 [CSS21].”

Comment: Pseudo-element definitions have been moved to other modules, leaving Selectors to define only the syntax and give a brief summary of the CSS1 and CSS2 pseudo-elements. Hopefully, they'll clarify this for `::before` and `::after` in the relevant module (possibly the fabled rewrite of the Generated/Replaced Content Level 3 module).

Answer (score 9):

I think that Chrome's behavior is invalid. If you [take a look here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-CSS21-20050613/generate.html#before-after-content), it says the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements add new `content` before or after the target element's `content`. Input elements have no `content`; they just have a `value`. You can't, for instance, do `<input>Pasta</input>`.

If all of this is true, then it would seem that Chrome's behavior is invalid, whereas IE and Firefox are correct.

Comment: Avoid linking to working drafts of specs that have already become recommendations, unless you're specifically referencing a draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

Comment: @BoltClock Good call. Sorry about that.

Comment: It seems like it is implemented in Safari too as of 2022, and works properly. The (fresher answers below)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/68634226/5125537] also indicate this. Regarding whether it is valid or not, is this answer still accurate? And if yes, then in what way will I experience the disadvantages of using `:before` and/or `:after` on my input invalidly?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's possible & cross-browser!

```
[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Safari */
}

[type=checkbox]::before {
  content: 'a text before';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely you can use that pseudo class
e.g: let's give the position of

`"input[type="checkbox"]"`
be relative and the position of the

`"input[type="checkbox"]:before"`
be absolute.

TRY THIS, it will work in chrome but not in firefox.