# Twitter Bootstrap radio/checkbox - how to put glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Using TB, is it possible to style the radio or checkbox so that it shows a glyphicon instead of the default style for radio or checkbox? I want to use a `glyphicon glyphicon-star` to indicate unchecked, then `glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty` to indicate checked.

Comment: There's no 'official' BS way to do that but you can use JS to hide the checkbox, replace with another element and attach the glyphicon states to that element (toggling the checkbox in the background).

Comment: glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty to indicate unchecked, then glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty to indicate checked? those are the same icons?

Comment: @Crystal - thanks for noticing the error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the official website, the javascript section has examples of styling groups of checkboxes and radio buttons as buttons groups. It's under the buttons section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons).

Instead of having text inside the button that reads "Option 1", you would place your glyphicon instead. If you wanted only one checkbox, I suppose you could eliminate the button group and just go with a single button.

To remove the button appearance and only show your icon, use the "btn-link" class.

I haven't tried this myself, but I see no reason for it to not work.

Answer (score 15):

Without javascript you could modify the style... Its kind of a hack in my opinion but it was interesting because I realized that boostrap uses an icon font #newb.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" >
```

CSS

```
.glyphicon:before {
     visibility: visible;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-star-empty:checked:before {
    content: "\e006";
}
input[type=checkbox].glyphicon{
     visibility: hidden;        
}
```

Try it out [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/t7gAR/1/)

Comment: Can you please check your fiddle? It doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I checked it; it works but what happens when you check it?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I updated it to use the icons that you wanted.

Comment: `::before` is not valid for input elements. This will work for Chrome but not for IE, Firefox. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831620/is-the-before-pseudo-element-allowed-on-an-inputtype-checkbox)

Answer (score 10):

Just for those, having the same problem and came from Google (I didn't find any convenient answer).

I tinkered something like this and tested it in the current Chrome, Firefox and IE. With this method, you also can use everything else you want as checkbox. Just give the classes "checked" and "unchecked".

For every checkbox do this:

```
<input id="checkbox1" class="icon-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1">
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked unchecked'></span>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check checked'></span>
  Checkbox 1
</label>
```

And add to your CSS:

```
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox{display:none}
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox+label .unchecked{display:inline}
input[type='checkbox'].icon-checkbox+label .checked{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox+label .unchecked{display:none}
input[type='checkbox']:checked.icon-checkbox+label .checked{display:inline}
```

Comment: This helped me considerably! I pretty much jsut pasted it in and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure angular solution to toggling between to glyphicon to conditionally show content on the page. I found the CSS solution to fail in IE.

This does more than your question, but I thought the toggling of something on the screen is useful.

```
<p ng-init="toggle = false" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" title="@Resources.Label_HideShowCustBiller" style="cursor:pointer" class="glyphicon" ng-class="{true: 'glyphicon-chevron-up', false: 'glyphicon-chevron-down'}[toggle]"></p>

<div ng-show="toggle">
    //what you want to show here
</div>
```