# Issue with angular radio input not populating the model when clicked

Tags: angularjs

I have a strange issue with a radio input not populating the model of an angular form.

All fields populate the model except for the radio input...

The radio input is given at the beginning of the form below. I use ng-inspector and I can see that signupForm.member.role does not get populated when I click one of the radio values.

Can someone please help?

```
<form name="formCtrl" ng-submit="signup(formCtrl)" class="col-xs-12" novalidate role="form">
    <h4>{{'SIGNUP_FORM_ROLE_PREFIX' | translate}}</h4>
    <div class="btn-group Choix col-xs-12 text-center" data-toggle="buttons" ng-class="getCssClasses(formCtrl, formCtrl.signupRole)">
        <label class="btn StateButton col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/parents.svg" />
            <input type="radio" name="signupRole" ng-model="signupForm.member.role" value="ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS" ng-required="true" />
            <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM_' + 'ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS' | translate}}</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn StateButton col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/professionel.svg" />
            <input type="radio" name="signupRole" ng-model="signupForm.member.role" value="ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCARE_WORKER" ng-required="true" />
            <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM_' + 'ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCARE_WORKER' | translate}}</span>
        </label>
        <div ng-messages="formCtrl.signupRole.$error" ng-if="formCtrl.$submitted">
            <div ng-message="required" class="control-label">{{'SIGNUP_FORM_ROLE_REQUIRED'| translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="getCssClasses(formCtrl, formCtrl.firstName)">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                   <span class="glyphicon icon-Prenom" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-minlength="2" placeholder="{{'SIGNUP_FORM_FIRST_NAME' | translate}}" ng-model="signupForm.member.firstName" ng-required="true" class="form-control" />
            <span ng-if="isSuccessFeedback(formCtrl, formCtrl.firstName)" class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon icon-Valid" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            <span ng-if="isErrorFeedback(formCtrl, formCtrl.firstName)" class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon icon-Erreur" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="formCtrl.firstName.$error" ng-if="formCtrl.$submitted">
            <div ng-message="required" class="control-label">{{'SIGNUP_FORM_FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED' | translate}}</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength" class="control-label">{{'SIGNUP_FORM_FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED' | translate }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lsaevbL0mBRku7zcrGDJ

One can notice that the radio is not taken into account when the form is submitted even if one of the radios is selected...

Comment: Please put your code in an interactive demo, press ctrl/cmd + m while editing your post and then add your dependancies. We would all love to help, just make it a little easier for us

Comment: a plunker would help

Comment: I am in the process of trying to put together a jsfiddle. Bear with me please.

Comment: I'm guessing from the data-toggle attr you're trying to use a JQuery plugin?

Comment: Yes. It is a jquery plugin (bootstratp)

Comment: I suggest either using a [pure css approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380296/re-styling-a-checkbox-in-bootstrap-3/28412799#28412799) or [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which provides a set of native AngularJS directives that you can use in lieu of the bootstrap.js.

Comment: I have added a working plunker (ignore the ugly labels please)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `value` instead of `ng-value`. Please see this working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2EB4NvTO1StN50NIXOyn?p=preview.

You should not use `ng-value`, which is looking for `$scope.ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS`.

Check [AngularJS.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D), the example there use:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.specialValue = {
    "id": "12345",
    "value": "green"
  };
```