# Styling Radio Inputs

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, radio-button

So I'm having major trouble with styling radio buttons and as such I've managed to get it working perfectly in Chrome, a tiny bit in Firefox and not at all in IE.

This is the expected look (in Chrome):
[image]

This is how it looks in Firefox:
[image]

And IE...

[image]

I've got a JSFiddle for you guys to play around with, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get this working cross-browser. Any ideas?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5rpd97b/

Obligatory paste of code despite the fact it's on JSFiddle anyway:

HTML:

```
   <input style="background: url(http://socialavatarnetworkscript.com/media/img/male_avatar.png);margin-right: 240px;" class="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="male">
   <input style="background: url(http://socialavatarnetworkscript.com/media/img/female_avatar.png)" class="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="female">
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"].gender::after{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    color: white;
    font-size: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
input[type="radio"].gender:checked::after{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    content: 'SELECTED';
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-family: titillium, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:    none;
    -ms-appearance:     none;
    appearance:         none;
    border-radius: 4px  !important;
    outline: none       !important;
    border: none        !important;
}
input[type="radio"].gender{
    height: 300px;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12831620/1127114

Comment: Simply don't use *form elements* like `input` for `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: `::after` is supposed to be rendered as if a new _child_ element was inserted into the element that it is applied upon – but `input` elements can’t have children. And formatting radio buttons cross-browser is tricky in any case. For more reliable results I’d suggest you use an extra element after each input, and use the adjacent sibling combinator `+` to format those depending on the input’s state.

Comment: I suppose doing this with a label is the most viable alternative?

Comment: It's a really bad practice to mix inline and external styles.... Because it'll be a pain for somebody else going through your code...

Comment: You get my special star of the day! *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements are inserted inside of the element that they are applied on. `:after` and `:before` shouldn't work with inputs as the `<input>` element cannot have children :(

The solution is to apply the images and `:after` pseudo element to the radio inputs label. From a semantics point of view it's also nice to give the label a value.

- The radio inputs are hidden with `display: none` and they are selected via their corresponding label attached with the matching `for` and `id` attributes.
- `input + label` targets only the label element directly after each input.
- `input + label:after` and `input:checked + label:after` provide the selected opaque overlay and transition animation

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/sumiq/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div id="welcome-gender"> 
    <input class="male" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" id="male-one">
    <label for="male-one">Male One</label>          

    <input class="female" name="gender" type="radio" value="female" id="female-one">
    <label for="female-one">Female One</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
label {
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.male + label {
    background: url(http://socialavatarnetworkscript.com/media/img/male_avatar.png);    
}
.female + label {
    background: url(http://socialavatarnetworkscript.com/media/img/female_avatar.png)
}

input + label:after {
    background: #FFF;
    content: '';    
}
input:checked + label:after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    content: 'SELECTED';
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-family: titillium, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: You've saved my bacon, you really have. Much appreciated.