# Place mask/unmask button inside a password input element

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCblH.png)

I want to add Eye-open bootstrap icon of toggling hide/show to my input field.
I already know the javascript to do it. I only want to how can I add that eye image to input field.

Found this html code from W3 school
 - for eye icon
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_eye-open

Comment: do you want on click eye the eye is hidden??

Comment: I just want to add eye ICON via bootstrap to input field.

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: You don't want what you ask you want, but you want to place a **button** inside an input. the icon part is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form-control-feedback` to `i` tag

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback"></i>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Edit to use fontAwesome instead bootstrap:https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_webapp.asp**

Use `:after` to `wrap`  div

```css
div:after{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: relative;
    left: -26px;
    content: "\f06e";
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
 <input name="username"">
</div>
```

Comment: What to do when using W3.CSS

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain?

Comment: I am already using W3.CSS library for my website and when I put this bootstrap code everythings gets messed up. I cannot use "form-control" with W3.CSS.

Comment: so you will not able to use this icons because it bootstrap icons... so what do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use W3.CSS library instead of bootstrap library.  https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_webapp.asp

Comment: Really Sorry don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 5):

## This is what you really after, a checkbox inside an input field

the checkbox toggles the password masking on "change" event

```js
document.querySelector('.toggleMask').addEventListener('change', onToggleMaskChange);

function onToggleMaskChange(){
  this.nextElementSibling.type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'
}
```

```css
.form-group{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; /* <-- just for demo */
  overflow:hidden;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  text-indent: -30px;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 2;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask ~ input{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask:checked::before{
  content:"\e105";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type='checkbox' class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close toggleMask"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

### For the commenter who asked for IE support:

```js
var toggleInput = document.querySelector('.toggleMask > input');
toggleInput.addEventListener('change', onToggleMaskChange);

function onToggleMaskChange(){
  
  this.nextElementSibling.className = this.checked 
    ? this.nextElementSibling.className.replace('open', 'close')
    : this.nextElementSibling.className.replace('close', 'open')
    
  this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'
}
```

```css
.form-group{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; /* <-- just for demo */
  overflow:hidden;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask{
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: -30px;
  text-indent: -30px;
  height:100%;
  line-height: 2;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask ~ input{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-group > .toggleMask:checked > span{
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='toggleMask'>
      <input type='checkbox' hidden/>
      <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close'></i>
    </label>
    <input type='password' class='form-control' />
</div>
```

Comment: @NateRadebaugh - IE? which version? `6`? `9`? `11`? please be specific what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. The above snippet does not render any icons when viewing using the latest version of IE (11.1000.18298.0) I think this is due to the CSS used: See this explanation here for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961271/valid-css-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11

Answer (score -1):

HTML Part:

```
<input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">`
```

JS Part:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
 }
```

You just might use this

Comment: You just copied and paste from w3schools SMH...and did not provide references.