# Checkboxes Mozilla Cross-Browser issue

Tags: html, css, checkbox, cross-browser, mozilla

I'm experiencing some issues with my checkboxes on Mozilla. The checkbox (on http://apespark.com/formifyPro/examples/login.html) works totally fine on Chrome, but on Mozilla it looks like the default checkbox. I tried and added`-moz-appeareance: none`, but as it seems it's not reading the pseudo (`::before` and `::after`) elements. I really can't understand and see why it's not displaying as supposed to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12833498/4334348

Comment: @silviagreen Thanks, but that doesn't really help me in any way. The problem is just discussed and no solution is given. Does this mean it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should style your label and not the input field.

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    // your styles here for text.

}
label:before {
    content:"";
    // styles here for the actual checkbox
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content:"";
    // styles here when checkbox is checked
}
```

to be safe you should change your html from a wrapping label like you have

```
<label><input /></label>
```

to a referencing one like so

```
<input id="myInput" />
<label for="myInput"></label>
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: Only issues I've had with wrapping labels is the lack of a parent selector in CSS... What exactly is the problem with using a wrapping label? It saves on locs and doesn't require `id` collision avoidance. (I have a feeling it's something IE related...)

Comment: im not sure if there is any difference.. just give it a try... i thought because css executes from top to bottom it may not work with the "input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before" selector.. :)

Comment: I must have zoned out when I was looking at this one and posted that... You're correct that you have to use `id`s to be able to be able to style the `label` differently when it is "checked", however, you absolutely _must_ do it that way due to a lack of parent selector. In other words, it's not even an option to use a wrapping label in this context.

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl Could you please, help. Tried what you've said and everything got messed up: http://apespark.com/formifyPro/examples/login.html

Comment: hm dont see the messup.. the checkbox now works in ff